# Why do I get weird results when I subdivide this mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

[image: mesh]

What do I do?

I subdivide then bend it, then this happens.

Comment: Your mesh isn't thick enough. Do you have a solidify modifier on there? If you do, up the thickness. Otherwise, you are going to have to grab the faces on one side of the mesh and pull them perpendicular from the mesh to create thickness.

Comment: Usually it works best to apply subsurf when your model is done. Try hiding subsurf, and adding solidify and see if that works better. Although solidify should be done first. More pictures, details of your model, or a .blend would help others inspect further.

Answer (score 3):

It could be one of a few things:

1. Make sure your mesh is thick enough and isn't intersecting with itself
2. Make sure your normals are calculated correctly (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
3. Make sure you don't have any doubled up vertices (select the vertices, hit <kbd>W</kbd>, and select *Remove Doubles*)
4. Make sure you don't subdivide with triangular faces as they don't deform nicely